# Split (Explode) String into Multiple columns and rows - Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, dataframe

Good afternoon, i am trying to split text in a column to a specfic format
here is my table below

```
UserId  Application
1       Grey Blue::Black Orange;White:Green
2       Yellow Purple::Orange Grey;Blue Pink::Red
```

I would like it to read the following:

```
UserId     Application          Role
    1       Grey Blue           Black Orange
    1       White               Green
    2       Yellow Purple       Orange Grey 
    2       Blue Pink           Red
```

So far my code is

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
idx=df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
df1=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({x:np.concatenate(df[x].values)} )for x in explode],axis=1)
df1.index=idx
return df1.join(df.drop(explode,1),how='left')

df['Application']=df.Roles.str.split(';|::|:').map(lambda x : x[0::2])

unnesting(df.drop('Roles',1),['Application'])
```

The following output code reads

```
UserId     Application          
        1       Grey Blue           
        1       White               
        2       Yellow Purple        
        2       Blue Pink
```

i do not know how to add the second column (role) in the code for the second split after ::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this dataframe:

```
   UserId                                Application
0       1       Grey Blue::Black Orange;White::Green
1       2  Yellow Purple::Orange Grey;Blue Pink::Red
```

you could at least achieve the last two columns directly via

```
df.Application.str.split(';', expand=True).stack().str.split('::', expand=True).reset_index().drop(columns=['level_0', 'level_1'])
```

which results in

```
               0             1
0      Grey Blue  Black Orange
1          White         Green
2  Yellow Purple   Orange Grey
3      Blue Pink           Red
```

However, defining `UserId` as index before would also provide the proper `UserId` column:

```
result = df.set_index('UserId').Application.str.split(';', expand=True).stack().str.split('::', expand=True).reset_index().drop(columns=['level_1'])
result.columns = ['UserId', 'Application', 'Role']

   UserId    Application          Role
0       1      Grey Blue  Black Orange
1       1          White         Green
2       2  Yellow Purple   Orange Grey
3       2      Blue Pink           Red
```

Comment: thank you for responding! i dont know what but the set index of user idk is not owrking, any thoughts? the error is a keyerror: 'UserId' @spghttcd

Comment: ok, that means your dataframe has an additional index and `UserId`is a normal column - I thought `UserId` was your index. I'll edit...